# ORA-02291: integrity constraint (GOPI.SYS_C007099) violated - parent key not found with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, oracle11g, transactions, entitymanager

I have implemented a project in hibernate with MySQL which works fine. But my client wants it in Oracle 11g but the following code throws me this error.

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (GOPI.SYS_C007099) violated - parent key not found

here is my following code with @oneToMany @ManyToOne relationship

I have 3 entities

1. Process
2. Process_analysis
3. Process_Steps

```
@Entity Process have 
@oneToMany  with
Process_analysis And
@oneToMany 
Process_Steps
```

Here is how I am persisting

```
Process_Steps  proSteps=new Process_Steps ();

        List<Process_analysis> pro_Anlist =new ArrayList<Process_analysis>();
        java.util.Date date=new java.util.Date();

        this.bean.setCancelled_Flg('F');
        this.bean.setUser_Id("xyz");
        this.bean.setpro_Status("xyz");
        this.bean.setPro_Description("dsfdfdfsdf");
        this.bean.setLast_Updated_Date(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
        proService.merge(this.bean); //Persisting or merging Process Entity

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        Process_analysis proAn=new Process_analysis();
        proAn.setCase_Protocal_Id("CASE:"+i);
        proAn.setPro(this.bean);
        proAnService.persist(proAn); //Persisting Each process analysis for Process NOTE:Throws Error Here 
        pro_Anlist.add(proAn);
        }

        proSteps.setRemarks("The StackOverflow");

        proSteps.setStart_Time(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
        proSteps.setEnd_Time(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
        proSteps.setPro(this.bean);           //Setting Foreign key of Process
        proStepsService.persist(proSteps);

        this.bean.getProAna().addAll(pro_Anlist);
        this.bean.getProSteps().add(proSteps);
        proService.merge(this.bean);`
```

### Process Entity

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="pro_que_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="pro_que_seq",sequenceName="pro_que_seq")
@Column(name="Pro_Id")
private Long Pro_Id;


public Long getPro_Id() {
    return Pro_Id;
}
public void setPro_Id(Long pro_Id) {
    Pro_Id = pro_Id;
}



@ElementCollection
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE, fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="Pro",targetEntity=ProInSteps.class)
private Collection<ProInSteps> ProInSteps=new LinkedHashSet<ProInSteps>();

@ElementCollection
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE, fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="Pro",targetEntity=ProAnalysis.class)
private Collection<ProAnalysis> ProAnalysis=new LinkedHashSet<ProAnalysis>();
```

### ProAnalysis

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="pro_an_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="pro_an_seq",sequenceName="ana_pro_seq")
private Long Analysis_Id;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="Pro_Id")
private Process Pro;
```

### ProInSteps

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="in_step_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="in_step_seq",sequenceName="pro_instep_seq")
private Long Pro_Step_Id;
private Timestamp Start_Time;
private Timestamp End_Time;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="Pro_Id")
private Process Pro;
```

Comment: The reason why this worked in MySQL is that you probably didn't define proper foreign keys there.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name :P so how do we persists the entity's have any idea ?? BTW i am able to persist Process and manually able to insert Process Analysis record...how can it be posssible ???

Comment: Please post the relevant mappings.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic i have added mapping please have a look

Comment: Why are you combining `@ElementCollection` with `@OneToMany`?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic no difference same error :(

Comment: No difference to what? :) What did you change?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic removed ElementCollection@ :(

Comment: Keep in mind that `merge` returns copy if argument is not managed. Try replacing `proService.merge(this.bean);` with `this.beain = proService.merge(this.bean);`